# AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'response2'

Tags: python, object, attributes

I have an issue by calling a object from another method. I have defined response in def `def sms_report(self):` as `self.response2 = self.ser.read(999)`, which should make it work globally. However I get this error calling it from another method. I can't figure out what's wrong with that. Many thanks in advance.

```
def sms_report(self):
    self.ser.write('AT+CMEE=2\r')
    self.response2 = self.ser.read(999)
    print(self.response2)

def send_sms(self):
    sms = Ui_MainWindow(str(self.lineEdit.text()), str(self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText().encode('ISO-8859-1')))
    repo = self.checkBox.isChecked()
    if repo == True:
        sms.sms_report()
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setPlainText(self.response2())
```

self.response2 is called here in the last line. Does anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the entire class which I'm working on... sorry for the length, but I'm a rookie!

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(503, 486)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 477, 391))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.gridLayout_2.setSpacing(6)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
    self.lineEdit_2.setDisabled(True)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.widget)
        self.radioButton.setChecked(True)
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.widget)
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit2.setObjectName("lineEdit2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_path) #connect add xls button with function get_path
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.widget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit, 2, 1, 2, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label2.setObjectName("label2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label2, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.send_sms) #send sms function
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.widget)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.line, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.connect_phone) #connect add xls button with function get_path
        self.plainTextEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.widget)
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_2")
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setDisabled(True)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit_2, 4, 1, 2, 1)
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.widget)
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.progressBar, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.widget)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.checkBox, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 503, 27))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName("mainToolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.radioButton.toggled['bool'].connect(self.lineEdit.setEnabled)
        self.radioButton.toggled['bool'].connect(self.lineEdit2.setDisabled)
        self.radioButton_2.toggled['bool'].connect(self.lineEdit.setDisabled)
        self.radioButton_2.toggled['bool'].connect(self.lineEdit2.setEnabled)
        self.radioButton.toggled['bool'].connect(self.pushButton.setDisabled)
        self.radioButton_2.toggled['bool'].connect(self.pushButton.setEnabled)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    self.plainTextEdit.textChanged.connect(self.bam)

    def bam(self):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    text = self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText()
        self.label2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", str(len(text))+"/160"))
    if len(text) > 160:
            root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(text[:160])
        cursor = self.plainTextEdit.textCursor()
        cursor.setPosition(self.plainTextEdit.document().characterCount() - 1)
        self.plainTextEdit.setTextCursor(cursor)
        tkMessageBox.showwarning("No Way!", "Keep it low, 160chrs max")
        root.destroy()
        root.mainloop()
        return

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Kotti&Co Mobilizer"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Single SMS"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SMS to Contacts"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add .xls"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Message Text"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Send it!"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Connect Phone"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Status Report"))

    def get_path(self, MainWindow): 
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Kotti Kontaktliste",filetypes = (("excel files","*.xls"),("excel files", "*.xlsx"),("csv files","*.csv"),("all files","*.*")))
    if not file_path:
        return None
    else:
        self.lineEdit2.insert(file_path)



    def __init__(self, recipient="+491749449785", message="TextMessage.content not set."):
        self.recipient = recipient
        self.content = message

    def setRecipient(self, number):
        self.recipient = number

    def setContent(self, message):
        self.content = message

    def disconnectPhone(self):
        self.ser.close()

    def connect_phone(self):
    try:
       self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 
                     460800, 
                     timeout=5, 
                     xonxoff = False,   
                     rtscts = False, 
                     bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS, 
                     parity = serial.PARITY_NONE, 
                     stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
       #s = input('Enter AT command --> ')
       #print ('AT command = ' + s)
       self.ser.write(bytes('AT+CGMI' + '\r\n'))
       self.ser.timeout = 1
       self.ser.write('AT+CGMM' + '\r\n')
       self.ser.timeout = 1
       response = self.ser.read(999)
       print(response)
       self.lineEdit_2.setText(response)

    except serial.SerialException: 
       self.lineEdit_2.setText("could not connect to phone")
       return None

    def check_phone(self):
    self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 
                     460800, 
                     timeout=5, 
                     xonxoff = False,   
                     rtscts = False, 
                     bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS, 
                     parity = serial.PARITY_NONE, 
                     stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

    def sendMessage(self):
        self.ser.write('ATZ\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write('AT+CMGF=1\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write('''AT+CMGS="''' + self.recipient + '''"\r''')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write(self.content + "\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write(chr(26))
        time.sleep(2)

    def sms_report(self):
    self.ser.write('AT+CMEE=2\r')
    self.ser.timeout = 3
        time.sleep(1)
    self.response2 = self.ser.read(999)
    print(self.response2)

    def send_sms(self):
    check = self.radioButton.isChecked()
    if check == True: #single sms use
        if not self.lineEdit.text():
            root = tk.Tk()
            root.withdraw()
            tkMessageBox.showwarning("Phone Number Missing!", "Please enter a valid phone number")
            root.destroy()
            root.mainloop()
            return
        if not self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText():
            root = tk.Tk()
            root.withdraw()
            tkMessageBox.showwarning("Message Missing!", "Please enter a text message")
            root.destroy()
            root.mainloop()
            return
        else:
            try:
                sms = Ui_MainWindow(str(self.lineEdit.text()), str(self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText().encode('ISO-8859-1')))
                sms.check_phone()
                sms.sendMessage()
                repo = self.checkBox.isChecked()
                if repo == True:
                    sms.sms_report()
                    self.plainTextEdit_2.setPlainText(self.lineEdit.text()+'\nmessage sent successfully'+self.response2())
                else:
                    self.plainTextEdit_2.setPlainText(self.lineEdit.text()+'\nmessage sent successfully')
                sms.disconnectPhone()
            except serial.SerialException:
                root = tk.Tk()
                root.withdraw()
                tkMessageBox.showwarning("NO GSM Connected!", "Plug in your mobile device")
                root.destroy()
                root.mainloop()
    else: #sms to contact sheet
        if not self.lineEdit2.text():
            root = tk.Tk()
            root.withdraw()
            tkMessageBox.showwarning("No contact sheet!", "Please add path to contact file")
            root.destroy()
            root.mainloop()
            return
        if not self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText():
            root = tk.Tk()
            root.withdraw()
            tkMessageBox.showwarning("Message Missing!", "Please enter a text message")
            root.destroy()
            root.mainloop()
            return
        else:
            try:
               with open(str(self.lineEdit2.text().encode('utf-8'))) as f:
                if str(self.lineEdit2.text().encode('utf-8')).endswith("csv"): #check whether the file is a .csv file or anything else
                        reader2 = csv.reader(f)
                    reader2.next()
                    linecount = len(zip(*reader2)[0])
                    f.seek(0)
                    reader = csv.reader(f)
                    reader.next()
                    #linecount = len(open(self.lineEdit2.text()).readlines())
                    counter = 0
                    count_all = 0
                        for i, (row) in enumerate(reader):
                        #print (row[0])
                        if not row[0] or row[0].startswith(tuple(ALPHA)): #avoid empty lines
                            counter += 1
                                continue
                        print (row[0])
                        sms = Ui_MainWindow("+491793288636", str(self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText().encode('utf-8')))
                        sms.check_phone()
                        sms.sendMessage()
                        count_all +=1
                        sms.disconnectPhone()
                        self.progressBar.setValue((count_all)*(100/(linecount-counter)))
                        if count_all == linecount-counter:
                            self.plainTextEdit_2.setPlainText('list completed')
                            self.progressBar.setValue(100)
                        else:
                            self.plainTextEdit_2.setPlainText(str(count_all)+'/'+str(linecount-counter)+'\n'+str(row[0])+'\nmessage sent successfully')
                else: #get the shit done for xls or xlsx files, converting them into data.csv
                    x =  xlrd.open_workbook(self.lineEdit2.text()) #hope that works in windoofs
                    worksheet = x.sheet_by_index(0)
                    csvfile = open('data.csv', 'wb')
                        writecsv = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

                        for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
                            writecsv.writerow(worksheet.row_values(rownum))
                    csvfile.close()
                    time.sleep(2)
                    with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
                            reader2 = csv.reader(f)
                        reader2.next()
                        linecount = len(zip(*reader2)[0])
                        f.seek(0)
                        reader = csv.reader(f)
                        reader.next()
                        print(linecount)
                        counter = 0
                        count_all = 0
                            for i, (row) in enumerate(reader):
                            #print (row[0])
                            if not row[0] or row[0].startswith(tuple(ALPHA)): #avoid empty lines
                                counter += 1
                                    continue
                            print (row[0])
                            sms = Ui_MainWindow("+491793288636", str(self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText().encode('utf-8')))
                            sms.check_phone()
                            sms.sendMessage()
                            count_all +=1
                            sms.disconnectPhone()
                            self.progressBar.setValue((count_all)*(100/(linecount-counter)))
                            if count_all == linecount-counter:
                                self.plainTextEdit_2.setPlainText('list completed')
                                self.progressBar.setValue(100)
                            else:
                                self.plainTextEdit_2.setPlainText(str(count_all)+'/'+str(linecount-counter)+'\n'+str(row[0])+'\nmessage sent successfully')
            except serial.SerialException:
                root = tk.Tk()
                root.withdraw()
                tkMessageBox.showwarning("NO GSM Connected!", "Plug in your mobile device")
                root.destroy()
                root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: These functions are in a class, correct?

Comment: yes exactly. they are all in the same class `Ui_MainWindow`, which is above defined as `class Ui_MainWindow(object):`

Comment: Additionally I think you are confusing where these methods are called. self refers to the object that the function is a part of. You can see sms is a Ui_MainWindow object and as such calling sms_report on it will save response2 to that object. self.response2 is looking for response2 in the object you ar calling send_sms from, which I assume is not the Ui_MainWindow.

If you want to fix it, dont create a new mainwindow, create a constructor instead and call self.sms_report()

Comment: If you can post the code, I'll show you how to structure it in the answer.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by constructor? I don't understand why I can call self.plainTextEdit_2 without any problems but not self.response2()!?

Comment: in the function you are creating a new object sms, and response2 is being saved to that object not to self. update the post with the entire class and I'll show you.

Comment: @arlyon I updated the post with the entire class above. sorry for the length of it and many thanks in advance!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132831/discussion-between-arlyon-and-fahrradlaus).